# Invalid binding path 'ViewModel.OpenProfile' : Property 'ViewModel' not found on type 'DataTemplate'

Tags: c#, uwp

Ошибку выдаёт в Command="{x:Bind ViewModel.OpenProfile, Mode=OneWay}"

```
 <StackPanel VerticalAlignment="Bottom" Orientation="Horizontal" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Spacing="10" Padding="20">
                                <StackPanel>
                                    <PersonPicture Width="50" Height="50"/>
                                </StackPanel>
                                <StackPanel>
                                    <winui:Expander>
                                        <winui:Expander.Header>
                                            <Button Content="PozitGo" Command="{x:Bind ViewModel.OpenProfile, Mode=OneWay}"/>
                                        </winui:Expander.Header>
                                    <winui:Expander.Content>
                                            <Button Content="Просмотр заказов"/>
                                        </winui:Expander.Content>
                                    </winui:Expander>
                                </StackPanel>
                            </StackPanel>
```

Comment: _Ошибку выдаёт в 8 строке_ - никогда так не пишите, здесь строки не нумеруются. Можно так попробовать `Command="{Binding ViewModel.OpenProfile, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=Window}}"/>` а как с `x:Bind` это сделать, к сожалению не знаю.

Comment: Насчёт строк понял, ваше предложение не помогло  
XDG0012 Член "AncestorType" не распознан или недоступен
XLS0413 Не удалось найти свойство "AncestorType" в типе "RelativeSource".